# to use request.GET for recursive [ [] ]

Tags: python, django, http-headers

I am trying to access values given by server response on django

> "GET
>   /customize/report/?sid=1&buzz_graph%5Btitle%5D=Buzz+Graph&buzz_graph%5Badded%5D=true&source_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Source+Distribution&geographic_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Geographic+Distribution&gender_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Gender+Distribution&age_group_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Age-group+Distribution&top_phrases%5Btitle%5D=Top+Phrases
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 8264

Since `%5B` and `%5D` are used as `[` and `]`.

I am not able to access the values using `request.GET['buzz_graph['title']']`. How to access such values from a response?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use " instead of ': request.GET["buzz_graph['title']"]. Or this is a mistake?

Comment: no it wont work that way either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no quotes - `buzz_graph%5Btitle%5D` is `buzz_graph[title]`, so what you want is:

```
request.GET['buzz_graph[title]']
```

Instead of your python-like `request.GET['buzz_graph['title']']`, which wouldn't work anyway as you need to escape the inner quotes for it to be part of the string (as it is, it would produce a syntax error).

Comment: i tried escaping the inner quotes and request.GET['buzz_graph[title]'] none works , thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's an appropriate answer, but key `'buzz_graph[title]'` works for me

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> QueryDict("""sid=1&buzz_graph%5Btitle%5D=Buzz+Graph&buzz_graph%5Badded%5D=true&source_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Source+Distribution&geographic_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Geographic+Distribution&gender_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Gender+Distribution&age_group_distribution%5Btitle%5D=Age-group+Distribution&top_phrases%5Btitle%5D=Top+Phrases""")
<QueryDict: {u'age_group_distribution[title]': [u'Age-group Distribution'], u'geographic_distribution[title]': [u'Geographic Distribution'], u'buzz_graph[title]': [u'Buzz Graph'], u'top_phrases[title]': [u'Top Phrases'], u'source_distribution[title]': [u'Source Distribution'], u'sid': [u'1'], u'buzz_graph[added]': [u'true'], u'gender_distribution[title]': [u'Gender Distribution']}>
>>> _['buzz_graph[title]']
u'Buzz Graph'
```

Comment: Why post an exact duplicate of my answer, half an hour later?

Comment: @Lattyware just give your answer a support, I cannot put this in a comment w/o breaking formats. I'd write it in your answer as an enhancement if fine